# How do I reconcile this truth table with the definition?

Tags: propositional-calculus

[image]

The circle and highlighted line confused me (logically, because I get the main idea) so I made a truth table, letting $P = x \notin A$ and $Q = x \in A ^\mathsf{c}$. Every truth assignment made sense except $P = F$, $Q = T$. If $P$ is false, is $x \in A$, and $Q$ is true, i.e., $x \in A ^\mathsf{c}$, how does that make the circled part true?

Comment: It's vacuously true, because the situation "$P=F$, $Q=T$" is impossible: how can the same $x$ be in $A$ and not be in $A$ in the same time?

Comment: @zipirovich OIC. I think remember earlier they stated the conditional was defined as if P false, Q true, then the statement is true to avoid/or get around situations life this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ ($x \not \in A$) is false and $Q$ ($x \in A^C$) is true, then the circled statement ('if $x \not \in A$ then $x \in A^C$') is true because the 'if' part is false and the 'then' part is true.... but you already knew that.   So I think your real question is "How is it possible for $P$ to be false and $Q$ to be true (when in fact they are of course saying the same thing)?"  Shouldn't the if ... then statement rule that out? And the answer is: No, the 'if $x \not \in A$ then $x \in A^C$' only rules out $x$ not being in $A$ ($P$ true) and $x$ also not being in $A^C$ ($Q$ false).  It is the *second* statement 'if $x \in A$ then $x \not \in A^C$' that rules out the possibility of $x$ being in $a$ ($P$ false) and $x$ also being in $A^C$ ($Q$ true).  So, between them, they *do* guarantee that $P$ and $Q$ say the same thing.